# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' K-Means; Custom code for K-Means

Tags: python, k-means, numpy, reshape

**Problem Statement**

The goal is to have the K-Means customer code run for clusters and not use scikit-learn libraries. Learning exercise. This K-means has the standard predict, fix, centroids, cluster means functions.

This is a data science coding programming question on creating a custom K-Means for machine learning so it is appropriate to ask here in the data science forum since resources will be keen on K-Means algorithms.

**My Attempt to Fix the Problem**

The TypeError unhashable appears to suggests that slicing on self.Centroids[:, k] is not working properly. I have already used a numpy arrays (np.asarray) to properly shape the array.

In the fix() function, first self attribute is casted to a numpy array before mutating the contents. The function name is has_fit(self, n_iterations) and the self.Centroids gets the self.getCentroids for the centroids in a numpy array.

**Shapes**

disparity_matrix.shape is (2700, 1)

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[218], line 5
      3 disparity_matrix = np.asarray(disparity_matrix)
      4 stars_model = CustomKMeans(disparity_matrix, n_clusters=2)
----> 5 start_model_fit = stars_model.has_fit(n_iterations=300)
      7 # Get cluster labels
      8 stars = np.asarray(stars)

Cell In[217], line 37, in CustomKMeans.has_fit(self, n_iterations)
     34 _euclidian = np.array([]).reshape(self.m, 0)
     35 for k in range(self.K):
     36     # Reshape the centroid column vector to be a 2D array
---> 37     centroid_column = self.Centroids[:, k].reshape(-1, 1)
     38     _distance = np.sum((self.X - centroid_column.T) ** 2, axis=1)
     39     _euclidian = np.c_[_euclidian, _distance]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

**Base Invocation Calls / Sequences**

My invoke python calls for my object:

```
disparity_matrix = np.asarray(disparity_matrix)
stars_model = CustomKMeans(disparity_matrix, n_clusters=2)
start_model_fit = stars_model.has_fit(n_iterations=300)
```

My Python K-Means Code

My class code is listed:

```
class CustomKMeans:
    def __init__(self, X, n_clusters=8, max_iter=300, tol=1e-4):
        self.X=np.asarray(X)
        self.Cluster={}
        self.Centroids=np.array([]).reshape(self.X.shape[1],0)
        self.K=n_clusters
        self.m=self.X.shape[0]
        
    def getCentroids(self,X,K):
        i = random.randint(0,X.shape[0])
        _centroid = np.array([X[i]])
        for z in range(1,K):
            _array = np.array([]) 
            for item in X:
                _array = np.append(_array, np.min(np.sum((item-_centroid)**2)))
            _probability = _array/np.sum(_array)
            _cummulative_probability = np.cumsum(_probability)
            _random = random.random()
            _jmp = 0
            for k, l in enumerate(_cummulative_probability):
                if _random < l:
                    _jmp = k
                    break
            _centroid = np.append(_centroid,[X[i]],axis=0)
        return np.asarray(_centroid.T)

    def has_fit(self, n_iterations):
        self.Centroids = self.getCentroids(self.X, self.K)

        for n in range(n_iterations):
            _euclidian = np.array([]).reshape(self.m, 0)
            for k in range(self.K):
                # Reshape the centroid column vector to be a 2D array
                centroid_column = self.Centroids[:, k].reshape(-1, 1)
                _distance = np.sum((self.X - centroid_column.T) ** 2, axis=1)
                _euclidian = np.c_[_euclidian, _distance]
            _centroid_adj = np.argmin(_euclidian, axis=1) + 1

            # Adjust the centroids
            _centroids = {}
            for n in range(self.K):
                _centroids[n + 1] = np.array([]).reshape(self.X.shape[1], 0)

            for o in range(self.m):
                # Reshape self.X[o] to match the shape of _centroids[_centroid_adj[o]]
                reshaped_X_o = self.X[o].reshape(-1, 1)  # Use -1 to infer the size along the first axis
                _centroids[_centroid_adj[o]] = np.c_[_centroids[_centroid_adj[o]], reshaped_X_o]

            for p in range(self.K):
                _centroids[p + 1] = _centroids[p + 1].T

            for q in range(self.K):
                self.Centroids[:, q] = np.mean(_centroids[q + 1], axis=0)

            self.Centroids = _centroids
        
    def has_cluster_means(self, X):
        cluster_means = []
        for i in range(self.n_clusters):
            points = X[self.labels == i]
            if len(points) > 0:
                cluster_mean = np.mean(points, axis=0)
                cluster_means.append(cluster_mean)
        return cluster_means
    
    def has_predict(self):
        return self.Clusters,self.Centroids.T
```

Answer (score 1):

The `self.Centroids` attribute starts by being a numpy array, which you can you index by row and column. However, later on, you overwrite `self.Centroids` by `_centroids` (last line of code in `has_fit`), which is a dictionary that cannot be index in the same way giving you the error.